# Making an Ajax call in Umbraco from inside user control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, umbraco

For an Umbraco project, I am trying to make a simple Ajax call.. I can't use PageMethods because I need to make the call from inside a UserControl..
I tried to do it via web service call like this:

Web service method:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MapService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCities(string ProvinceCode)
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

JS part in my ASCX file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function callServer(src) {
        MapService.GetCities(src, displayMessageCallback);
    }

    function displayMessageCallback(result) {
        fillDDL(result);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, "MapService.GetCities" method doesn't get invoked..

What might be the problem here?

Alternatively, what is there any better way to make these kind of Ajax calls in a User Control?

Answer (score 2):

I've been usign the Umbraco base REST Extensions for this kind of thing. I think it's a lot simpler to implement and if you use a JSON Serialiser on the server you even have proper JSON objects on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Use **REST method** for doing this. we have implemented this for our projects. For this you have to edit the **restExtensions.config** and add your entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that the javascript inside the usercontrol does not communicate with the scriptmanager in the page.
I can see two ways of dealing with this.
1. Use jQuery to call the webmethod instead of asp.net ajax.
2. through the control javascript call a method in the page javascript which will call the webmethod, i.e. use the page as a proxy. This has the added advantage of enabling you to use a page method instead of a web service.